# Mongo aggregation framework: group users by age

Tags: mongodb

I have a user base stored in mongo. Users *may* record their date of birth.
I need to run a report aggregating users **by age**.

I now have a pipeline that groups users by year of birth. However, that is not precise enough because most people are not born on January 1st; so even if they are born in, say, 1970, they may well not be 43 yet.

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    { $match : { "DateOfBirth" : { $exists : true} } },
    { $project : {"YearOfBirth" : {$year : "$DateOfBirth"} } }, 
    { $group : { _id : "$YearOfBirth", Total : { $sum : 1} } },
    { $sort : { "Total" : -1 } }
])
```

Do you know if it's possible to perform some kind of arithmetic within the aggregation framework to exactly calculate the age of a user? Or is this possible with MapReduce only?

Comment: I think `$subtract` operator is suitable for your task, but unfortunately it doesn't support `Dates` in current stable version :)

Comment: Well, if the date is stored in millis, the solution could be in substraction of milliseconds (as long type) and then convert it to the Date format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like the whole thing is possible with the new Mongo 2.4 version just released, supporting additional Date operations (namely the "$subtract").

Here's how I did it:

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    { $match : { "DateOfBirth" : { $exists : true} } },
    { $project : {"ageInMillis" : {$subtract : [new Date(), "$DateOfBirth"] } } }, 
    { $project : {"age" : {$divide : ["$ageInMillis", 31558464000] }}},
    // take the floor of the previous number:
    { $project : {"age" : {$subtract : ["$age", {$mod : ["$age",1]}]}}},
    { $group : { _id : "$age", Total : { $sum : 1} } },
    { $sort : { "Total" : -1 } }
])
```

Comment: isn't the '%' in "new Date()%" a typo? Btw, great answer.

Comment: Hm, doesn't handle leap years though, as far as I can tell. How about integrating something like this?

Comment: function isLeap(year){
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
  }

Comment: could use a $cond but you'd need to add a projected field via $year

Answer (score 2):

There are not enough dateTime operators and math operators to project out the date. But you might be able to create age ranges by composing a dynamic query:

Define your date ranges as cut-off dates as

dt18 = today - 18
dt25 = today - 25
...
dt65 = today - 65

Then do nested conditionals, where you progressively use the cut off dates as age group markers, like so:

```
db.folks.save({ "_id" : 1, "bd" : ISODate("2000-02-03T00:00:00Z") });
db.folks.save({ "_id" : 2, "bd" : ISODate("2010-06-07T00:00:00Z") });
db.folks.save({ "_id" : 3, "bd" : ISODate("1990-10-20T00:00:00Z") });
db.folks.save({ "_id" : 4, "bd" : ISODate("1964-09-23T00:00:00Z") });


db.folks.aggregate(
    {
    $project: {
        ageGroup: {
            $cond: [{
                $gt: ["$bd",
                ISODate("1995-03-19")]
            },
            "age0_18",
            {
                $cond: [{
                    $gt: ["$bd",
                    ISODate("1988-03-19")]
                },
                "age18_25",
                "age25_plus"]
            }]
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$ageGroup",
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
})
```